# HTaccess dynamic URL to static rewrite that works both ways without loop

Tags: .htaccess

I have looked through stack overflow and can't find the exact answer I am looking for so here goes.

I have a URL 
http://holtplantandmachinery.co.uk/cat/wheel-loaders which redirects to http://holtplantandmachinery.co.uk/category.php?name=wheel-loaders

However I need it to work the other way around when you enter the dynamic URL it rewrites to the static (folder looking) URL above and vice versa. Essentially whatever one is called it should rewrite to the static one. Now I know I need to setup a rewrite that works the opposite way to the one above and then have a condition to stop an infinite loop but I can't seem to get anything to work please help.

Answer (score 0):

When someone types `http://holtplantandmachinery.co.uk/category.php?name=wheel-loaders` into the browser's URL address bar, the request sent to the *holtplantandmachinery.co.uk* server looks something like:

```
GET /category.php?name=wheel-loaders HTTP/1.1
Host: holtplantandmachinery
some other headers
etc
```

You can use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` var to match against the first line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ category\.php\?name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /cat/%2? [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect the request to `http://holtplantandmachinery.co.uk/cat/wheel-loaders` and that URL will show up in the browser's URL address bar. The reason why you use `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead of `%{QUERY_STRING}` is because when your other rule that rewrites the nicer looking URL to the one with the query string, it'll look and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` would match, the rule would get applied and cause a redirect loop. Alternatively, you could match against the query string and use a:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
```

To ensure the URI wasn't from a previously rewritten internal redirect.

Then you'd have your internal rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?cat/(.*)$ /category.php?name=$1 [L]
```